# 'float' object is not subscriptable / from putting float into dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

```
value_temp = p.split(';')
value = round(float(value_temp[2]),5)
for i in range(24):
    df_1.loc[i] = [1,date[0],value[i]]
print(df_1)
```

I split a string. What I want to do is extract the values from string and change it to float, and then put it into DataFrame. But I'm getting error from putting values in a DataFrame.

Comment: Where does this error occur in your code? Please provide sample data to reproduce the problem, or at least the full traceback

Comment: what are you doing with the for loop? It looks like value is a single float. Why are you iterating through a range of 24 and taking each number in the float? Can you provide us with what p looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
p = "1;2;3;4;5;6"
p.split(';')
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

n = [float(x) for x in p.split(";")]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c','d','e','f']})
df['num'] = n
```